# JavaFX on Linux

Tags: linux, javafx-2, javafx, java

What is the situation with JavaFX on Linux (x86 and x64)?

Can a JavaFX app be executed without problems on Linux OS?

I have found some questions from years 2011 and 2012, when apps were not stable!

Comment: According to the roadmap: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html it is stable since 2.2.

Comment: As far as I can see, it is certified only on Ubuntu 10.4+, according to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html ! I should support other Linux distributions, and was experiencing some issues on other distributions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current version of JFX released is 2.2.4 and it is quite stable on Linux. However, it will become very much better when Java 8 would be released as it would contain JFX 8 distibution. You can try it yourself now using java 8 early access builds.

Comment: I think its worth mentioning the user has to have Oracle's JRE since most people on Linux have OpenJDK/OpenJRE and that seems to be scheduled to have full JavaFX support with Java 9.

Comment: Java 9? Will we even be alive when that comes out?

Comment: @AndreiRînea hello java 10

Comment: @Okx: WOW! At first I thought it was plain trolling but after a quick search it seems it is true. Never hoped.

Answer (score 5):

JavaFX 8 runs fine on Linux in my experience, the only requirement appears to be libgtk 2.18+. There are full details on [Oracle JDK 8 and JRE 8 Certified System Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html). Working Linux versions include:

- Ubuntu 10.04 (and possibly earlier, 10.04 had libgtk 2.20)
- Redhat 6

Possible problems you may encounter

- 3D scene support - requires specific modern GPUs + recent drivers, note there is no software rendering fallback for this, and no plans to - see [mailing list question](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.openjfx.devel/8256)
- Video playback requires certain version of libavcodec
- OpenJDK does not yet include javafx, only the oracle distribution. Update July 2016 - openjfx package now available .on Ubuntu 16.04...

Answer (score 0):

Javafx runs on JVM(Java Virtual Machine) like all other java applications. It doesn't matter whether you run the javafx application on windows or linux or mac there is no doubt that it will not run. That's why  java is called platform independent language. Now stable version of javafx 8 has been released with more features.

Comment: In practice this is not true because JavaFX is not a pure Java implementation, it has a lot of native code behind it to do things like OpenGL, heavy-weight components, video playback etc...